# List vector print does not work

Tags: c, list, hashtable

I'm doing a hash table, where I have a one vector with a list inside each node of it. But when I go to print it does not appear the items that are within the list, and if I try to put more than one element in the list, it gives segmentation failure in the second. Below is the code and the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
enum erro {
     semErro = 0, posInv = 1, listaCheia = 2, listaVazia = 3, existe         = 4, naoExiste = 5
};

typedef struct no{       
    char nome[100];
    char telefone[20];
    struct no *prox;
} nodo;

typedef struct{
    int tamanho;
    nodo *inicio;
} lista;

typedef struct { 
    int tamanhoTabelaHash;
    int colisoes;
    lista* vetor;
} tabela;

///////////////////Chamada de Funções///////////////////
lista *novaLista();
tabela *criaTabela(int tam);
int insereTabela(tabela *tabela, char *entraNome, char *entraTelefone);
int insereNoInicioI(lista *lista,char *entraNome, char *entraTelefone);
int hash1(char *entraNome, int tam);
void imprime(lista *lista);
void imprimeTabela(tabela *tabela);
///////////////////Funções Lista///////////////////

void imprime(lista *lista){        
     int i;
     nodo *no; //<<<<<Possível local do erro>>>>>
     puts("Lista: \n");
     for (i = 0; i < lista->tamanho; i++) {  
          printf("Nome: %s Telefone: %s\n",no->nome,no->telefone);
          no=no->prox;
     }
}

lista *novaLista(){ 

     lista *l = (lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
     l->tamanho=0;
     l->inicio=NULL;
     return l;
}

int insereNoInicioI(lista *lista,char *entraNome, char *entraTelefone){ 

     nodo *novo=(nodo *)malloc(sizeof(nodo));    
     strcpy(novo->nome,entraNome);
     strcpy(novo->telefone,entraTelefone);
     novo->prox = lista->inicio;
     lista->inicio = novo;        
     lista->tamanho++;
     return semErro;
}

tabela *criaTabela(int tam) {

    if( tam < 1 ) return NULL;
    tabela *table = (tabela *)malloc(sizeof(tabela));
    table->tamanhoTabelaHash = tam;
    table->colisoes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   
        table[i].vetor = NULL;
    }
    return table;   
}

void imprimeTabela(tabela *tabela) {

    int i;
    printf("\nTabela: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < tabela->tamanhoTabelaHash ; i++) {
        printf("\nindice[%d]:", i);
            if(tabela[i].vetor!=NULL){
               imprime(tabela[i].vetor);
            }  
    }
}

int insereTabela(tabela *tabela, char *entraNome, char *entraTelefone){

    int pos = 0;
        pos = hash1(entraNome,10000);//Função que retorna uma posição( no caso 8 para o primeiro nome e 6 para o segundo e terceiro
    }
    if(tabela[pos].vetor==NULL){
        lista *list = novaLista();
        tabela[pos].vetor = list;
    }
    nodo *novo=(nodo *)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    insereNoInicioI(tabela[pos].vetor, entraNome, entraTelefone);
    return semErro;
} 

int main(){
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
   tabela *table = criaTabela(10);

   char nome[100] = "Maria Cláudia Feliz";
   char telefone[20] = "(53)98401-8583";
   char nome1[100] = "Everton Almeida";
   char telefone1[20] = "(53)90000-8583";
   char nome2[100] = "Everton Almeida";
   char telefone2[20] = "(53)90000-8583";

   insereTabela(table,nome,telefone);
   insereTabela(table,nome1,telefone1);
   insereTabela(table,nome2,telefone2);
   imprimeTabela(table);
return semErro;
} 
Resultado:
Tabela: 
indice[0]: 
indice[1]:
indice[2]: 
indice[3]: 
indice[4]: 
indice[5]: 
indice[6]:Lista: 
Nome:  Telefone:  //<<<<Deveria imprimir o nome e telefone>>>>
Nome:  Telefone:  //<<<<Deveria imprimir o nome e telefone>>>>
indice[7]: 
indice[8]:Lista:
                  //<<<<Deveria imprimir o nome e telefone>>>>
Falha de segmentação(imagem do núcleo gravada)
```

If you can help, thank you.

Comment: Easiest way to find the bug is probably just to single-step it through your debugger.

Comment: Have you run the code in a debugger so you can step through and see what's happening and where the crash happens? You appear to have a typo in the code that keeps it from compiling, and extra `}`, but if that is fixed it still won't compile since the `hash1` function is missing.

Comment: Pasted code simply don't compiles fine

code.c:94:5: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘if’
     if(tabela[pos].vetor==NULL){

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Except for fixing some compilation errors still the hash1 function is missing in your code.

Comment: `nodo *no; //<<<<<Possible error location>>>>>` .. Yes you are correct here because you have missed initializing `no` and accessing unintialized pointer in the `for` loop. Initialize `no` with `lista->inicio` before accessing it.

Comment: Thanks H.S I did what you informed me and it worked out I'm editing the code for the correct one

Comment: If you edit the code to a working state, this question becomes no longer a question. (You can always delete it if that's what you want.)

Comment: @H.S. Please answer in the answer section, not in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm right now I'm new here. If you can help with the accent issue, thank you too.

Comment: @EvertonAlmeida which _accent issue_? This is another question, post another question please.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least one serious problem here:

```
tabela *criaTabela(int tam) {
  if (tam < 1) return NULL;

  // you allocate space for 1 tabela
  tabela *table = (tabela *)malloc(sizeof(tabela));
  table->tamanhoTabelaHash = tam;
  table->colisoes = 0;

  // but here you write to 10 tabelas ....
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    table[i].vetor = NULL;
  }
  return table;
}
```

You if you write to 10 tabelas, you should allocate space for 10 tabelas:

```
  tabela *table = (tabela *)malloc(sizeof(tabela) * 10);
```

The code in your answer yields in undefined bahaviour. In other works it may *appear* to work. Google *"undefined bahaviour"*.

There may be more problems elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you, I did what you told me and it worked perfectly well with 10 but if you put more than 100 for example 100 it error.

Comment: It only _appeard_ to work with 10. You are overwiting memory that you have never allocated. Your program yields in undefined behaviour (google that term). Undefined behaviour includes "apparently working fine".  For example on my computer it crashes even with 10

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your comment correctlky, but if you have `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)`, the you need to allocate space for 100: `tabela *table = (tabela *)malloc(sizeof(tabela) * 100);`

Comment: Thank you, I did what you told me and it worked perfectly. I was forgetting to change the value in the IF. But now it's working.

Comment: @EvertonAlmeida if this answer was helpful, you are supposed to upvote and/or [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it so other users will see that the answer was useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
enum erro {
     semErro = 0, posInv = 1, listaCheia = 2, listaVazia = 3, existe         = 4, naoExiste = 5
};

typedef struct no{       
    char nome[100];
    char telefone[20];
    struct no *prox;
} nodo;

typedef struct{
    int tamanho;
    nodo *inicio;
} lista;

typedef struct { 
    int tamanhoTabelaHash;
    int colisoes;
    lista* vetor;
} tabela;

///////////////////Chamada de Funções///////////////////
lista *novaLista();
tabela *criaTabela(int tam);
int insereTabela(tabela *tabela, char *entraNome, char *entraTelefone);
int insereNoInicioI(lista *lista,char *entraNome, char *entraTelefone);
int hash1(char *entraNome, int tam);
void imprime(lista *lista);
void imprimeTabela(tabela *tabela);
///////////////////Funções Lista///////////////////

void imprime(lista *lista){        
     int i;
     nodo *no = lista-> inicio; 
     puts("Lista: \n");
     for (i = 0; i < lista->tamanho; i++) {  
          printf("Nome: %s Telefone: %s\n",no->nome,no->telefone);
          no=no->prox;
     }
}

lista *novaLista(){ 

     lista *l = (lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
     l->tamanho=0;
     l->inicio=NULL;
     return l;
}

int insereNoInicioI(lista *lista,char *entraNome, char *entraTelefone){ 

     nodo *novo=(nodo *)malloc(sizeof(nodo));    
     strcpy(novo->nome,entraNome);
     strcpy(novo->telefone,entraTelefone);
     novo->prox = lista->inicio;
     lista->inicio = novo;        
     lista->tamanho++;
     return semErro;
}

tabela *criaTabela(int tam) {

    if( tam < 1 ) return NULL;
    tabela *table = (tabela *)malloc(sizeof(tabela)*10);
    table->tamanhoTabelaHash = tam;
    table->colisoes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   
        table[i].vetor = NULL;
    }
    return table;   
}

void imprimeTabela(tabela *tabela) {

    int i;
    printf("\nTabela: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < tabela->tamanhoTabelaHash ; i++) {
        printf("\nindice[%d]:", i);
            if(tabela[i].vetor!=NULL){
               imprime(tabela[i].vetor);
            }  
    }
}
int hash1(char *string, int tam) {

    int tamanho = strlen(string);
    unsigned soma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        soma = soma * 251 + string[i];
    }
    return soma % tam;
}

int insereTabela(tabela *tabela, char *entraNome, char *entraTelefone){

    int pos = 0;
        pos = hash1(entraNome,10);
    if(tabela[pos].vetor==NULL){
        lista *list = novaLista();
        tabela[pos].vetor = list;
    }
    nodo *novo=(nodo *)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    insereNoInicioI(tabela[pos].vetor, entraNome, entraTelefone);
    return semErro;
} 

int main(){
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
   tabela *table = criaTabela(10);

   char nome[100] = "Maria Cláudia Feliz";
   char telefone[20] = "(53)98401-8583";
   char nome1[100] = "Everton Almeida";
   char telefone1[20] = "(53)90000-8583";
   char nome2[100] = "Everton Almeida";
   char telefone2[20] = "(53)90000-8583";

   insereTabela(table,nome,telefone);
   insereTabela(table,nome1,telefone1);
   insereTabela(table,nome2,telefone2);
   imprimeTabela(table);
return semErro;
} 
Resultado:
indice[0]:
indice[1]:
indice[2]:Lista: 
Nome: Everton Almeida Telefone: (53)90000-8583
indice[3]:
indice[4]:
indice[5]:Lista: 
Nome: Everton Telefone: (53)90000-8583
indice[6]:
indice[7]:
indice[8]:Lista: 
Nome: Maria ClÃ¡udia Feliz Telefone: (53)98401-8583
indice[9]:
```

Thanks to all comments THIS IS THE CODE WORKING, but I have one more doubt, because the name clause goes wrong if the setlocale (LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

Comment: This code is incorrect and yields in undefined behaviour, see my answer.